# better cucumber (Capybara-based) selection when multiple similar fields appear in a form

Tags: checkbox, cucumber, capybara

> (Some background if it helps: our Rails app has a bunch of potentially repetitive dynamically-generated forms using double-nested fields, with ids in the pattern foo_attributes_0_bar_attributes_0_bat_12, where basically the first two numbers increment based on how many repetitions of the nested form there are, and the last number is the id of the particular "bat" object. This makes selection in Cucumber for testing difficult!)

I am trying to write some steps like this:

```
When I check the 1st checkbox with the value "Bat 12"
```

or

```
When I check the 3rd checkbox with id matching "bar_attributes_bat"
```

I have the following working, but my method of finding the checkboxes (or fields) seems pretty crappy and inefficient to me:

```
When /^I check the (\d+)(st|nd|rd|th) checkbox with the value "([^"]*)"$/ do |number, junk, value|
  check(page.all("input").select {|el| el.node['value'] == value}[(number.to_i-1)].node['id'])
end

When /^I check the (\d+)(st|nd|rd|th) checkbox with id matching "([^"]*)"$/ do |number, junk, id_string|
  check(page.all("input").select {|el| el.node['id'] && el.node['id'].match(/#{id_string}/)}[(number.to_i-1)].node['id'])
end
```

Is there a better way to select these input elements?

Comment: Note: I just found input[type='checkbox'] here thanks to the sidebar so that is some help. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
When /^I check the (\d+)(st|nd|rd|th) checkbox with the value "([^"]*)"$/ do |index, junk,   value|
  page.all("input[value='#{value}']")[index.to_i-1].check
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of xpath to click(check) the checkbox.here i use the same which had two input field,first one is hidden and second one is visible.here i click the second.

my html for checkbox taken from firefox.

```
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="approve[enabled]"/>
<input id="3" class="approveClass" type="checkbox" value="1" name="approve[enabled]"/>


//*[@id='MyList']/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/input[2]
```

my checkbox is on the third column with no label in a table.for example

```
 name                              type                         approve        
 rocky                             permanent                    [](checkbox)


#step in my scenario...
 And I press xpath link "//*[@id='userList']/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/input[2]"

#web_step.rb......
    When /^I press xpath link "([^"]*)"$/ do |xpath|
      page.find(:xpath, xpath).click
    end
```